# How to count the number of monthly archive?

Tags: categories, archives, wp-get-archives

```
<?PHP
$num_cats  = wp_count_terms('category'); 
echo $num_cats. '<br/>';    
?>
```

I get the number of total categories from the above code. How can I get the total categories based monthly archive? following code is not echoing the number of monthly archive:

```
<?php 
$num_month_cats  = wp_count_terms (get_archives('monthly')); 
echo $num_month_cats;
?>
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "total categories based monthly archive"? Of what do you want the count, exactly?

Comment: number of monthly archive.. ex : if my site has Jan 2014, feb 2014, Mar 2014.. then the number of monthly archive is 3